# Does a linearly accelerating spherically symmetric body emit gravitational waves

Tags: general-relativity, forces, waves, gravity, gravitational-waves

According to Birkhoff's Theorem, any spherically symmetric body will not emit gravitational waves. I can understand this for an object that is contracting and expanding because from far away the gravitational force is the same. But now imagine, we have a spherically symmetric body that is linearly accelerating through free space. In this case, would gravitational waves be emitted ?

Comment: "but I can't visualise this." Can you visualize the gravitational waves?

Comment: @A.V.S. I read this as a spherical uniform mass with a linear acceleration, I think that's not too much of a stretch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> According to Birkhoff's Theorem, any spherically symmetric body will not emit gravitational waves. <…> But now imagine, we have a spherically symmetric body that is linearly accelerating through free space. In this case, would gravitational waves be emitted?

Gravitational waves are emitted by *systems*, and not by individual components of systems. If the “system” is a single spherically symmetric body (that may be expanding or contracting while keeping its spherical symmetry) then we can apply Birkhoff's theorem and conclude that no gravitational waves are emitted.

But a linearly accelerating body cannot be the system *by itself*: it does not satisfy the constraints on the sources of Einstein equations. So we *must* include in the analysis some external entity producing this acceleration. This entity clearly violates the spherical symmetry of the system, so *Birkhoff's theorem here cannot be applied*, and the nature and geometry of this entity would determine whether gravitational waves are emitted.

In particular, to determine gravitational radiation we cannot calculate quadrupole moment of *just* the single accelerating body as suggested in the answer by secr.

There is an exact solution of Einstein equations, *Kinnersley's photon rocket*, that has a mass moving along arbitrary trajectory (including, possibly, with constant linear acceleration) due to recoil from a photon stream it emits. This solution does not have gravitational radiation, gravitational field contributions from the mass and from photon stream cancel each other near null infinity. This cancellation is fairly unique: almost any other mechanism to accelerate the mass would produce gravitational radiation, but the important point here is that gravitational waves are either produced or not jointly by a system including both body and an entity inducing acceleration.

Comment: @aP123 Is there a photon fluid a in your setup?

Comment: Isn’t that’s stupid, pedantic and wrong? Like saying that the speed of a falling apple can’t scale with t because there isn’t a physically meaningful potential that would create such a movement?

Comment: @secr There are levels of “physically meaningful”. For some questions unbounded velocity growth can indeed be the wrong answer. But the minimum requirement is the mathematical consistency. Accelerating by itself mass fails constraint $\nabla_aT^{ab}=0 $, so it cannot be the (only) source term in EFEs. This is like asking what would be the EM field, when the charge suddenly disappeared. But one can ask what the EM field would be when two opposite charges annihilate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would produce waves. Its position and hence its mass distribution relative to a fixed point changes over time, so the quadrupole moment is changing. Since it is accelerating, the second derivative of the quadrupole moment will be non-zero, leading to gravitational waves.

Comment: How would linear momentum be conserved in that case? (Let's say that our spacetime is asymptotically flat, so global conservation laws are meaningful.) A mass can accelerate only if something else accelerates it and the gravitational far field stays the same. (In my opinion at least, but I am not an expert on this.)

Comment: It wouldn’t  be conserved

Comment: @ramiel46692   " the conservation laws which result can be considered to be the most fundamental principles of mechanics. In mechanics, examples of conserved quantities are energy, momentum, and angular momentum. The conservation laws are exact for an *isolated system*.".(italics mine). your accelerated body is not isolated http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/conser.html . as some force is accelerating it.

Comment: @annav I know, but that wasn’t the point of the question of OP, or was it?

Comment: @annav Yes, 'it is not conserved' when you phrase it like that, but my point was something else.  You can state that linear momentum is conserved, since our model spacetime is asymptotically flat. In this vacuum, there is only our body in question, and our propellant (whatever that might be, even if it is a field). When the acceleration hapens, the center of mass stays the same, momentum is conserved, the far field stays the same as well, and there is no radiation. (I am still guessing, but nobody has convinced me yet.)

Comment: No, the centre of the mass doesn't stay the same and it accelerates and creates waves. With your line of a argument, the mass density could do whatever it wants due to some far away fields and wouldn't create waves as long at it keeps it's spherical symmetry as viewed from the centre of it's mass (e.g. oscillate).

Comment: @secr It seems like in some cases there would be gravitational waves, while in other cases there would be none. Fx. an exact solution is Kinnersley's photon rocket (that is linearly accelerated by photons), and it does not emit gravitational waves. [link](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9412063)

Comment: @ramiel46692 They have a photon fluid, we don't.

Comment: @secr Now that I have found papers about the C metric [link](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/263874134_Gravitational_radiation_of_accelerated_sources) and also have read this: [link](https://www.mathpages.com/rr/s6-08/6-08.htm) I am more or less convinced that it would radiate. But I will definiately come back to this topic when I know more about frame dragging/gravitoelectromagnetism/gravitational waves.

Comment: @A.V.S. Our mass doesn’t do that

Comment: @A.V.S. Nothing is moving with c. I don't get your point and I think you're wrong. You apply the expansion around the origin, i.e. where everything rests, that's all.

Comment: I explained my reasoning (and your error) in my own answer.